# Can XXE be exploited when disallow-doctype-decl is set to true (Apache)?

Tags: webserver, java, xml, xxe

I found out that an endpoint of a website may be vulnerable to XXE. It is using `Unmarshal` as an XML parser.  When I try to send a post request using common XXE payloads, I receive the following response from the server:

`[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 54; DOCTYPE is disallowed when the feature \"http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl\" set to true.]`

Is there any payload that doesn't need the doctype declaration?
Is it possible to exploit this XXE or not?

Comment: Did you ever find a way? Maybe an X-include attack? https://portswigger.net/web-security/xxe#xinclude-attacks